# rails NoMethodError: undefined method `helper_method' for ApplicationHelper:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-api

I have followed this [tutorial](http://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails) and its working correctly.

[updated after below answer]
I have moved the code to the Application Controller (previously defined as a helper) to determine if the current user is logged in

```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user

    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]

  end
end
```

I have created a module to create a client object and make an api call, this functionality may be used by one or more objects so it seemed like a good idea to create it as a module instead of a controller.

```
  require 'base64'
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'json'
  require 'google/api_client'
  require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
  require 'net/https'
  require 'uri'

module GoogleClient

  include ApplicationController


  PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'

  # Build the global client
  $credentials = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("#{Rails.root}/config/client_secret_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")
  $authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :authorization_uri => $credentials.authorization_uri,
    :token_credential_uri => $credentials.token_credential_uri,
    :client_id => $credentials.client_id,
    :client_secret => $credentials.client_secret,
    :redirect_uri => $credentials.redirect_uris.first,
    :scope => PLUS_LOGIN_SCOPE)
  $client = Google::APIClient.new(options = {:application_name => 'xxx-xxx-xxx'} )

  def GoogleClient.get_people

    if current_user

      # Authorize the client and construct a Google+ service.
      $client.authorization.update_token!(current_user.oauth_token.to_hash)
      plus = $client.discovered_api('plus', 'v1')

      # Get the list of people as JSON and return it.
      response = $client.execute!(plus.people.list,
        :collection => 'visible',
        :userId => 'me').body
      content_type :json
      puts response

    else

      redirect_to root_url

    end
  end
end
```

the user model is;

```
require 'google_client'


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include GoogleClient

 # after_save GoogleClient.connect


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    where(provider: auth["provider"], uid: auth["uid"]).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|

      user.provider = auth.provider

      user.uid = auth.uid

      user.name = auth.info.name

      user.email = auth.info.email

      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token

      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)

      user.save!

    end
```

testing it in the console results in

2.1.0 :001 > GoogleClient.get_people
NoMethodError: undefined method `helper_method' for ApplicationHelper:Module

Is it possible to call to a helper method in a module?  How should I implement this code if a module is incorrect

** update Correct module code but the api request has a redirect uri error ** explained here in this [post](http://www.codercaste.com/2012/09/02/how-to-create-a-module-in-rails-and-when-to-do-it/)

"Notice that modules in /lib are not automatically loaded. Instead, you will need to add this line in your config/application.rb file file config block :"

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Google::GoogleClient

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    where(provider: auth["provider"], uid: auth["uid"]).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|

      user.provider = auth.provider

      user.uid = auth.uid

      user.name = auth.info.name

      user.email = auth.info.email

      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token

      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)

      user.save!

    end
  end

  if current_user

    self.get_people()

  else

    redirect_to root_url

  end
end
```

'lib/google/google_client.rb'

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'

module Google

  module GoogleClient

    # Initialize the client.
    client = Google::APIClient.new(
      :application_name => 'xxx-xxx',
      :application_version => '1.0.0'
    )

    # Initialize Google+ API. Note this will make a request to the
    # discovery service every time, so be sure to use serialization
    # in your production code. Check the samples for more details.


    # Load client secrets from your client_secrets.json.
    client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("#{Rails.root}/config/client_secret_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")


    # Run installed application flow. Check the samples for a more
    # complete example that saves the credentials between runs.
    flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
      :client_id => client_secrets.client_id,
      :client_secret => client_secrets.client_secret,
      :scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me']
    )
    client.authorization = flow.authorize

    def get_people

      # Make an API call.
      result = client.execute(
        :api_method => plus.activities.list,
        :parameters => {'collection' => 'public', 'userId' => 'me'}
      )

      puts result.data

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Move both of these to ApplicationController:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

helper_method :current_user
```

That will give you a `current_user` method that works in controllers, helpers, and views.

Comment: same error after method is defined in the ApplicationController and removed from the ApplicationHelper

Comment: You're still getting 'undefined method helper_method' in ApplicationHelper??? If so, you're still trying to call `helper_method` in a helper.  It can only be called in a controller.

Comment: Correct, changed to include the ApplicationController but now new error

`2.1.0 :001 > GoogleClient.get_people
TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
`

Should I be putting this in a controller because it relies on other Controller Methods?